# java.lang.RuntimeException: How do I solve this crash? And what is causing this?

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, developer-console

I get this crash report displayed in my Developer Console and I have aboslutely no Idea what it means:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3319)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3415)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:229)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1821)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7406)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:551)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:380)

  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)

  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:161)

  at com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:91)

  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6904)

  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1136)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3266)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:794)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:716)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:847)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 

  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:4249)

  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:4156)

  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:4006)

  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:886)

  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:157)

  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:145)

  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:72)

  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:68)

  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)

  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)

  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)

  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:758)
```

On Line 91 is following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So I think it has to do something with the XML file.
Here is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainview">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/main_color"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:title="My App" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_ico"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">



        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            />


    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added the ImageView with the search Icon last update and the constrain layout, before I added this everything worked fine.
The users with Android Version 6 cannot open the app.
Please help me fix this issue, thank you!

Comment: not so familiar with this stuff bug ... *Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException ...at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:4249)* does that mean smthg to you? Image missing or so?

Comment: Check whether `ic_search_white_24dp` is present in `drawable` folder in your project's `res` directory or not?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Just checked it, it had a (v24) behind its name. Could that be the error?

Comment: Yes, Check my answer

Comment: ha, my humble contribution cleared the path to the summit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition with `drawable-v24` you also have to add `ic_search_white_24dp` in `drawable` folder of your project's `res` directory to support devices API level lower than 24.

Comment: I just removed the file and copied it in the normal drawable folder. I no longer have it in the drawable-v24 folder. Is that okay or do I have to put it in both?

Comment: Yes it's fine. If you put it on default `drawable` folder then it's work on all devices

Comment: You are welcome. Also hit the upvote please